# Is there any needs of adding constraints for the DDL?

Tags: sql, computer-science, ddl

```
create table Country(
    code char(3)        PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar2(100)  NOT NULL
 );

create table Member(
    firstname varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
    title varchar(100)      NOT NULL,
    member_id INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY,
    Country_code char(3)    NOT NULL REFERENCES Country(code)
                            ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );

create table Athlete(
   id integer           NOT NULL REFERENCES Member(member_id)
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE

);

create table Official(
   id integer           NOT NULL REFERENCES Member(member_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

create table Staff(
   id integer           NOT NULL REFERENCES Member(member_id)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE                   
);

Create table Books(
   when timestamp       NOT NULL,
   member_id integer        NOT NULL REFERENCES Member(member_id),

   start_time timestamp NOT NULL REFERENCES Journey(start_time),
   start_date date      NOT NULL REFERENCES Journey(start_date),
   byStaff integer      NOT NULL REFERENCES Staff(id)
);


create table Journey(
    start_time timestamp    PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date date     PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id integer       PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Member(member_id),
    nbooked integer     NOT NULL,
    departure varchar(100)  NOT NULL REFERENCES Place(name),
    arrival varchar(100)    NOT NULL REFERENCES Place(name),
    code varchar(100)       NOT NULL REFERENCES Vehicle(code)
 );

create table Vehicle(
    code varchar(100)       PRIMARY KEY,
    capacity varchar(100)   NOT NULL
 );

create table Place(
    name varchar(50)        PRIMARY KEY,
    address varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    longitude float     NOT NULL,
    latitude float`     NOT NULL
 );

create table SportVenue(
   name varchar(50)         NOT NULL REFERENCES Place(name)
);

create table Accommodation(
   name varchar(50)         NOT NULL REFERENCES Place(name)
);

create table Event(
    name varchar(100)       PRIMARY KEY,
    result_type varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    time timestamp      NOT NULL,
    date date           NOT NULL,
    sport_name varchar(50)  NOT NULL REFERENCES Sport(name),    
);
```

For the DDL above, is there any needs of adding constraints for the DDL? If it needs to be modified, which constraints should be implemented? I am so confused on writing DDL... wef ewf ew fwe fewf wef oiwejf oiwej fioejwo ifjewo ifwjeoif jewoiew fiowefioje w
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "total participation constraint" ?, please explain, preferably using examples of input data and expected result for this data.

Comment: `wef ewf ew fwe fewf wef oiwejf oiwej fioejwo ifjewo ifwjeoif jewoiew fiowefioje` <= what does that mean?

Comment: What is the purpose of having a table with one column?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints aka validation should be implemented from all sides of your application. Front-end, back-end, and your database.  Otherwise, you would fail on the overall data integrity. So, the answer to your question is yes. Details depend on the nature of the data you will be working with.